# Creating a dynamixel action client controller (Tutorials)

Tags: dynamixel, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am following the tutorial for dynamixel_contollers as posted on http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_controllers/Tutorials/Creatingdynamixelactionclient

When I run "trajectory_client.py", in the console where I run controller_manager.launch show: Incoming trajectory joints do not match the joints of the controller. Exception in your execute callback: not all arguments converted during string formatting.

Also when I run the start_meta_controller before, at the end it appears: all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor complete.

Thank you very much for your attention.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285892/creating-a-dynamixel-action-client-controller-(tutorials)/) by [Montes](https://answers.ros.org/users/31916/montes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have already solved it, the fault was in the line: goal.trajectory.joint_names. You have to remove: +char.

---

Originally posted by [Montes](https://answers.ros.org/users/31916/montes/) with karma: 16 on 2018-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0